# Github Pull Requests: How can I prevent "unjustified" change markings?

Tags: git, github, pull-request

Our Github pull requests are full of "non-changes" like this:

[image]

I generally understand that these are related to recent code changes that were merged into this branch. But I thought one of the reasons for merging is to absorb such changes and not have to subsequently deal with them as differentiated code.

I have a vague sense that this could be being triggered by inconsistent line-ending CR/LF settings amongst the project team. but can't find any information that provides clarity on how to get where I want: the github pull request should show *only* the true code differences between two commits.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One way to deal with it is to add `?w=1` at the end of the diff URL, that way it'll show only lines that don't have whitespace issues.

Comment: Thanks. I tried that just now but it doesn't appear to have an effect.

Comment: Can you post the full URL before and after?

Comment: I was doing it wrong. When I tried again, your suggestion had a big, positive effect. I'd still like to understand the root cause and how to address it, (or failing that, how to make w=1 the default), but regardless this helps quite a bit.

Comment: Here's something annoying: when it's in "w=1" mode, you can't add comments. argh.

Comment: Yes, it's not perfect. There used to be a Chrome extension that would add a few things like that. Not sure if that one exists anymore